# Does react native support sample-level audio callback from microphone source?

Tags: react-native, html5-audio, audio-recording, react-native-ios, audio-analysis

I hope to make an app based on React Native in which I can capture audio frame by frame and perform DSP analysis. Is there any library based on React Native that support this type of function? Thanks.